# Duplicate data in not getting removed from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have the below program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
std::string value;
    std::vector<std::string>v;
    v.push_back("tuhin");
    v.push_back("tsp");
    v.push_back("tsp");
    v.push_back("gonit");
    v.push_back("tuhin");

    for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i=v.begin();i!=v.end();i++)
    {
         std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    cout<<"===================="<<endl;
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
    for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i=v.begin();i!=v.end();i++)
    {
         std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
}
```

while removing the the duplicate its still giving duplicate value

output:
tuhin tsp tsp gonit tuhin ====================

tuhin tsp gonit tuhin

See tuhin is repeating

Comment: std::unique only works with sorted terms.

Comment: Read the documentation for the algorithms you use. `std::unique` needs a **sorted range**.

Comment: Then how can i remove the value for unsorted vector

Comment: @tuhinpanda, sort the vector first then apply unique to it. Otherwise, use an `std::unordered_set`

Answer (score 0):

From c++ reference for `std::unique`:

> **Remove consecutive duplicates in range**
>
> Removes all but the first element from every **consecutive** group of equivalent 
>     elements in the range [first,last).

What you need to do is:

> std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
>
> v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());